# Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `8e7c86-5982-4e5-88-fcbc65e0`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, warnings

So, I have a structure where I am supposed to clone the exisitng field selected by user. Whenever I click **clone** button, it should clone the values automatically.

here are few important states in my logic

```
    const [aggData, setAggData] = React.useState(
        {
            id: 11,
            dateFrom: null,
            dateTo: null,
            bucket: null,
            records: [
                { id: KocoUtils.uuidv4(), vehicle: null, signal: null, aggFunc: null},
            ]
        });
```

```
    const hanldeCloneRecord = (record) => {
        let newData = _.cloneDeep(aggData);
        newData.records.push(record);
        setAggData(newData);
    };
```

```
                                <Button
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        hanldeCloneRecord(record);
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <span className="flex sm:hidden">{'Clone Metric'}</span>
                                </Button>
```

Whenever I click the clone button, the warning appears and it keeps looping itself and my program crashes.

What could be the error here?

I tried to change change the ID of the **newData.record** array but it did not help. I also tried to assign

```
aggData.id = KocoUtils.uuidv4()
```

But no luck !!

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use clone deep? Could you instead change `handleCloneRecord` to be `const handleCloneRecord = (record) => setAggData(prevAggData => ({...prevAggData, records: [...prevAggData.records, {...record, id: KocoUtils.uuidv4()}]}));`

Comment: Hi, I need cloneDeep because I need to copy the same record with the same values beneath the existing one as soon as a user clicks on the clone button.

Comment: @sumowrestler I tried your solution and no warning is there. But, again I was not able to clone the record I have selected before pressing the clone button.